# Can you create a Python list from a string, while keeping characters in specific keywords together?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create a list from the characters in a string, but keep specific keywords together.

For example:

keywords: car, bus

INPUT:

```
"xyzcarbusabccar"
```

OUTPUT:

```
["x", "y", "z", "car", "bus", "a", "b", "c", "car"]
```

Answer (score 38):

With `re.findall`. Alternate between your keywords first.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "xyzcarbusabccar"
>>> re.findall('car|bus|[a-z]', s)
['x', 'y', 'z', 'car', 'bus', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'car']
```

In case you have overlapping keywords, note that this solution will find the first one you encounter:

```
>>> s = 'abcaratab'
>>> re.findall('car|rat|[a-z]', s)
['a', 'b', 'car', 'a', 't', 'a', 'b']
```

You can make the solution more general by substituting the `[a-z]` part with whatever you like, `\w` for example, or a simple `.` to match any character.

Short explanation why this works and why the regex `'[a-z]|car|bus'` would not work:
The regular expression engine tries the alternating options from left to right and is "*eager*" to return a match. That means it considers the whole alternation to match as soon as one of the options has been fully matched. At this point, it  will not try any of the remaining options but stop processing and report a match immediately. With `'[a-z]|car|bus'`, the engine will report a match when it sees any character in the character class [a-z] and never go on to check if 'car' or 'bus' could also be matched.

Comment: Great solution. Using `'[a-z]|' + '|'.join(keywords)` would make it easier to build the regex programmatically.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan Thanks. It would be `'|'.join(keywords) + '|[a-z]'`, though, the order is critical because the regex engine tries the alternatives from left to right and is *eager* to return a match. That's why the solution works, maybe I should edit in an explanation.

Comment: Ah, silly me! I don't use much regex, and I just thought the other order would be more readable.

Answer (score 16):

```
s = "xyzcarbusabccar"
import re

print re.findall("bus|car|\w", s)
['x', 'y', 'z', 'car', 'bus', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'car']
```

Or maybe `\S` for any non whitespace chars:

```
s = "xyzcarbusabccar!"
import re

print re.findall("bus|car|\S", s)
['x', 'y', 'z', 'car', 'bus', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'car', '!']
```

Just make sure you get the order correct putting longer words first if you want the longest matches.

```
In [7]: s = "xyzcarsbusabccar!"

In [8]: re.findall("bus|car|cars|\S", s)
Out[8]: ['x', 'y', 'z', 'car', 's', 'bus', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'car', '!']

In [9]: re.findall("bus|cars|car|\S", s)
Out[9]: ['x', 'y', 'z', 'cars', 'bus', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'car', '!']
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions are really great, but if the keywords dictionary is long it can easily become messy(maybe unimplementable).

I propose to store the keywords in a tree (which exploits redundancy) and is more space efficient.

If the keywords are `["art,"at","atm","bus","can","car"]` the dictionary looks like this

```
                 .
                 ^
            /    ¦      \

          /      ¦        \
        a        b           c
        ^        ^           ^
      /   \       \           \
    r       t      u           a
    ^       ^      ^           ^
   /       /  \     \        /   \
  t       m   /0     s      n     r
  ^       ^          ^      ^     ^
 /      /             \      \     \
/0     /0             /0      /0   /0
```

I made it binary since it was easier to draw. The node `"/0"` has the significance of word end (virtual character) and `"."` is the root.

I implemented this simple Tree class to build the tree and necessary functions

```
class Tree(object):

    def __init__(self, name='root', children=None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = {}
        if children is not None:
            for child in children:
                self.add_child(child.name,child)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def add_child(self, node):
        assert isinstance(node, Tree)
        self.children[node.name] = node


    def has_child(self,name):
        return name in self.children

    def get_child(self,name):
        return self.children[name]

    def print_tree(self,level=0):
        sys.stdout.write('-' * level)
        print self.name
        for childTag in self.children:
            self.children[childTag].print_tree(level+1)
```

Given the keywords we can construct the structure using code like this

```
keywords = ["car","at","atm","bus"]
keywordsTree = Tree('')

for keyword in keywords:
    keywordsTreeNode = keywordsTree
    for character in keyword:
        if not keywordsTreeNode.has_child(character):
            keywordsTreeNode.add_child(Tree(character))
        keywordsTreeNode = keywordsTreeNode.get_child(character)

    keywordsTreeNode.add_child(Tree('/0'))
```

Finally we search the input for keywords. The solution below offers for a given position in the input all of the keywords matched starting from that position.

```
inputWords = "xyzcarbusabccar8hj/0atm"
output = []
lengthInput = len(inputWords)
for position in range(0,lengthInput):
    ##add by default the character
    # allMathcedKeyWords = [inputWords[position]]

    allMathcedKeyWords = []
    keywordsTreeNode = keywordsTree
    searchPosition = position
    curMathcedWord = ''

    while searchPosition < lengthInput and keywordsTreeNode.has_child(inputWords[searchPosition]) :

        keywordsTreeNode = keywordsTreeNode.get_child(inputWords[searchPosition])
        curMathcedWord = curMathcedWord + inputWords[searchPosition]

        if (keywordsTreeNode.has_child("/0")):
            allMathcedKeyWords.append(curMathcedWord)

        searchPosition += 1

    if len(allMathcedKeyWords)==0:
        allMathcedKeyWords = inputWords[position]

    output.append(allMathcedKeyWords)

print output
```

This code outputs this

```
['x', 'y', 'z', 
 ['car'], 
 'a', 'r', 
 ['bus'], 
  'u', 's', 'a', 'b', 'c',   
 ['car'],
  'a', 'r', '8', 'h', 'j', '/', '0', 
 ['at', 'atm'], 
  't', 'm']
```

Important for the code above is the fact that the virtual character at the end of words is two letters (`"/0"`) and will never be matched (even if the combination appears in the input sequence as detailed above). Furthermore it handles any string character (for the input and keywords - also do not need to introduce escape characters as in `re.findall()` )

From this output list you can decide what you want to do. If you want the solution of `re.findall` find the longest matched word for a position (or based on keywords logical order) and jump ahead the number of characters that word contains.

Taking the problem even further, every character in the input is a vertex and when you find a word add an edge from that position to the corresponding next vertex after the last character of the matched word. A shortest path algorithm will give you again the solution above. Structuring the output like this bring again space efficiency and opens the door to more complex algorithms.

Example, having keywords `"car"` and `"art"` and art and input sequence `"acart"` the resulting graphs looks like this

```
             ______________
            ¦              ¦
- a -> c -> a -> r -> t ->
       ¦______________¦
```

Complexity analysis

```
Space : longest_word_length * number_of_letters_in_keywords
        input_length + input_length * input_length (worst case-fully connected graph)
Time  : input_length * longest_word_length
        input_length + input_length * input_length (worst case-fully connected graph)
```